# How to do it visible with Stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to do something like this[image]
What I got right now:

[image]

My problem is the top view at the bottom center button. Is half visible. But also I want the bottom view, to be a scroll view of texts with no space from to bottom button from the top view (the half-visible). Hope I explained well.

What code looks like:

```flutter
class TopView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  TopView(this.id);
  final String distance = '2.834 km';
  final String image =
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537953773345-d172ccf13cf1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(image),
            ),
          ),
        ),
       Widget(...),
       Widget(...),        
       Widget(...),
       Widget(...),        
       Positioned(
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 70.0,
          bottom: -30.0,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              MiddleButton(isLeft: true, iconData: Icons.add),
              MiddleButton(
                isLeft: false,
                iconData: Icons.airplanemode_active,
                rotate: true,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MiddleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLeft;
  final bool rotate;
  final IconData iconData;
  MiddleButton(
      {@required this.isLeft, @required this.iconData, this.rotate = false});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 70.0,
      height: 60.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: kWhite,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(isLeft ? 50 : 0),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(isLeft ? 50 : 0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(isLeft ? 0 : 50),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(isLeft ? 0 : 50),
        ),
      ),
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: rotate ? 45 * pi / 180 : 0,
        child: Icon(
          iconData,
          color: kBlack,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add this `overflow: Overflow.visible` to the stack parameters

Comment: It works, is deprecated, and now instead of `overflow` is `clipBehavior: Clip.none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by adding `clipBehavior: Clip.none` inside the `Stack` component